# How to print an n-bit number with a custom n-length character set in JavaScript without using toString

Tags: javascript, string, integer

In the same way we have the hex "number" using the characters `123456789abcdef`, and you can simply do `integer.toString(16)` to go from integer to hex:

```
> (16).toString(16)
'10'
```

... I would like to instead use a custom character set, and a custom base. So for hex say I wanted to use the characters `13579acegikmoqsu`, then it would be something like this:

```
> (16).toString(16, '13579acegikmoqsu')
'ik'
```

I don't actually know what the output value would be in this case, just made that up. But I am looking for how to do this in JavaScript.

Another example outside of hex would be a, for example, base 6 number converted to a string using the character set `and123`, so it would be something like this:

```
> (16).toString(6, 'and123')
'a3d'
```

I don't know what the value is in this case here either, I don't know how to calculate it. Basically wondering how to do this in JavaScript, not necessarily using this `toString` api, preferably it would be a bit more low-level so I could also understand the logic behind it.

Likewise, it would be helpful to know how to reverse it, so to go from `a3d => 16` as in this pseudo-example.

Comment: `> (16).toString(16, '13579acegikmoqsu')` result should be `31`

Comment: It seems that you need a sort of map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map the character values of the integer value as index

```js
function toString(n, characters) {
    var radix = characters.length;
    return Array
        .from(n.toString(radix), v => characters[parseInt(v, radix)])
        .join('');
}
 
console.log(toString(16, '13579acegikmoqsu')); // 31
```

A version without `toString` and `parseInt`.

```js
function toString(n, characters) {
    var radix = characters.length,
        temp = [];

    do {
        temp.unshift(n % radix);
        n = Math.floor(n / radix);
    } while (n)

    return temp
        .map(i => characters[i])
        .join('');
}
 
console.log(toString(16, '13579acegikmoqsu')); // 31
```

Comment: For the sake of performance one could use fixed charset sample like '0123456789abcdef'. Though this would apply limitation for the base.

Comment: Wondering if you could show this without using `toString()`, maybe even without `parseInt`.