# Encode ArrayBuffer of arbitrary length to custom alphabet

Tags: javascript, string, encoding

I have had a few questions about how to convert integers into custom alphabet, and some stuff about encoding which I still don't fully understand yet, but I'm getting there. What I'm wondering about now though is how to convert an *arbitrary-length* ArrayBuffer (basically just a bunch of bits of arbitrary length), into a custom alphabet (without using major library helpers like JavaScript `toString` or `parseInt` or others).

So this value is bigger than the max integer by far, as you could have a whole paragraph or document as input.

From my understanding so far, I would do this:

```
var array = new Uint8Array(500000)
array[0] = 123
array[1] = 123
array[2] = 123
// ... fill it in with some stuff.

stringify(array.buffer, '123abc') 
// encode to 6-character alphabet, such as:
// 1a2ba3caa13a...
```

Then I feel stuck... There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54556680/169992) helpful example on how to do it for integers. But I am having difficulty applying it to this new situation.

Also would be helpful to know how to convert it back into the ArrayBuffer from the string that used the custom alphabet, so it would go both ways.

The conversion of the `array.buffer` to some example output like `1a2ba3caa13a...` would happen similar to the radix stringifying in the linked question (well, I don't know how it work work actually). But it would go through the bits somehow and basically encode them somehow using characters from the custom alphabet, like hex encoding, base64 encoding, etc.

Comment: You mean like [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) but using a 6bits table only? You'll create huge outputs... What's the use case?

Comment: Yeah basically that, but using _any_ custom sized alphabet, not just the one I exampled.

Comment: Would it make sense to include a little more about how that conversion is working in this question? I may be naive, but to me converting to a custom alphabet could mean a few different things, and it was only when I saw in the linked question that this was similar to hex conversion that this made sense to me.

Comment: @OliverRadini OP basically wants a BaseN encoding. Though honestly, this sounds kind of a do-my-job question: while it may take long time to write it, the basics is trivial, with a bit of research on similar encodings.

Comment: Good news, someone already made it: https://github.com/sumory/baseN

Comment: @Kaiido No! That is `Number` based so it's not _arbitrary length_ :)

Comment: What do you mean? You can create an UInt8 view of your ArrayBuffer with arbitrary length. You just have to map every val with the encoder.